# What if marginal costs coincide with the produced quantities?

Tags: finance, economics

Its stated in *Cabral 2013,p158* that in equilibrium price under Cournot competition is greater than price under perfect competition but lower than monopoly price.

Is this still would be true if the marginal costs coincide with the produced quantities?

The market that we are considering is for homogeneous goods, the demand is linear, marginal cost is constant and equal across all firms and smaller than the maximum willingness to pay.

Comment: What are your thoughts? How does the profit function does look like in your opinion?

Comment: Well, the problem is that the marginal cost following the produced output doesn't make any sense. Because as we know if the marginal cost increases the quantity should go down and price should up.(under Cournot and Monopoly) 
Only in perfect competition might make sense but not for Cournot and monopoly.